# Call dll (C++ library) methods from Java

Tags: java, dll, jnaerator

I have .dll library with header file written in C++ (no source code available). This library uses some another .dll files - i have them too. My task is to use this library from Java (call methods and receive results).

I found that it is possible to use JNAerator for this purpose. What algorithm will be? I tried `java -jar jnaerator.jar MyLib.dll MyLibHeader.h` command but it outputs

```
 ERROR: JNAeration failed ! 

     Missing output mode parameter -mode !
     Please use -h for help on the command-line options available.
```

How to use -h for help? Which -mode i need? There is only one dll in example command but i want to use three of them as they depends on each other.

May be it is more suitable tool for my task? (Some tutorials will be appreciated). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `-mode` argument in your command line.
Their [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CommandLineOptionsAndEnvironmentVariables) page has this to say:

> -mode [mode: 'Jar' : JAR with bindings only | 'StandaloneJar' : JAR with bindings and runtime dependencies | 'Directory' : Bindings sources in simple file hierarchy | 'Maven' : Bindings sources in Maven project ready to build | 'AutoGeneratedMaven' : Maven project that automatically regenerates its bindings>]

Let's say you use 'StandaloneJar', then your command line would be:
`java -jar jnaerator.jar -mode StandaloneJar MyLibHeader.h MyLib.dll`.

I hope it works, since I have absolutely no experience with JNAenerator!